# Atributo de una clase abstracta proveniente de otra clase dentro del mismo paquete

Tags: java

Buenas.

Tengo un problema con eso: me mandan hacer un paquete con varias clases, la primera clase es "cliente" (con atributos idCliente y nombre), la segunda es "Cuenta". La clase "Cuenta", es abstracta donde uno de sus atributos es "titular" y me pide que este atributo sea del tipo "Cliente", ya que va asociado al nombre. No dice que tengan ningun tipo de herencia, pero si estan dentro del mismo paquete.

Estoy empezando, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio MeN, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Comment: Buenas, gracias por el tutorial. Realmente estoy atascado, no puedo poner nada porque no se ni como empezar con la pregunta que tengo. No obstante, tendre todo en cuenta para futuras preguntas.

Comment: MeN te agrego un tutorial de como crear una clase y sus atributos (propiedades) https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/Java/Objetos-y-Clases  revisalo y trata de realizarlo para que preguntes con mas detales

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya he respondido con algo más detallado. Espero que sea más acorde con las normas.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno gracias por el tutorial Jorgesys. Lo he leído y eso más o menos lo sé. Vamos por partes; hago la clase "Cliente", con visivilidad privada y con los atributos y metodos que pide:

```html
public class Cliente {
    
    private int idCliente;
    private String nombre;
    private String direccion;
    private String telefono;
    
    public Cliente (){
        
    }
    
    public Cliente (int idCliente, String nombre, String direccion, String telefono){
        
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        
    }
    
    public int getIdCliente(){
        return idCliente;
    }
    
    public void setIdCliente(int idCliente){
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
    }
    
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public String getDireccion(){
        return direccion;
    }
    
    public void setDireccion(String direccion){
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }
    
    public String getTelefono(){
        return telefono;
    }
    
    public void setTelefono(String telefono){
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
```

Hago la clase "Cuenta", que pide que sea abstracta, visibilidad protegida y con estos atributos y metodos:

```html
public abstract class Cuenta {
    
    protected int numeroDeCuenta;
    protected double saldo;
    protected xxxxx titular;
    
}
```

Y ahí me quedo atascado, en esas "xxxxx". Pide que el atributo "titular" sea del tipo "Cliente", osea, de la clase cliente. ¿Alguna pista de como implementarlo desde dicha clase a la abstracta?

Comment: Me parece que tienes que leer de nuevo el tutorial.
`protected int numeroDeCuenta;` Donde `protected` es si la accesibilidad del dato, `int` Es el tipo de dato y `numeroDeCuenta` es el nombre del atributo

si te dice que el tipo de Dato sea Cliente, entonces que tendrías que poner en las xxxxx

La respuesta es sencilla pero no la pondré porque es básica y te servirá mucho. Dedúcela.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir, pero creo que no es eso lo que piden. Entiendo que dices que ponga `protected int titular`, pero es que lo que creo que hay que hacer es que ese "titular", enlace con el atributo de la clase "Cliente". El ejercio pone concretamente: titular-> atriburo de tipo Clietne que representa la persona que está asociada a dicha cuenta. Entiedo que es como una especie de herencia o union entre esos dos atributos, pero ambas clases no pide que esten heredadas. Estoy empezando, quiza no me explique bien...

Comment: Estás mal, `protected int titular` haría que el atributo fuera `int` en lugar de `Cliente` int es un tipo de dato, pero por ejemplo en caso de nombre de `String` Es una clase por lo que no solo puedes refernciar los atributos como tipo de datos sino también como clase, es decir tú bien puedes hacer `protected Cliente titular` y convertirás el atributo titular como un objecto del tipo Cliente y será tratado como tal. He ahí la solución, pero es importante que entiendas esto porque es básico en Java

Comment: Gracias, ahora si parece que ya encaja. No sabia que era tan sencillo como poner el nombre de la clase `Cliente` en el lugar del tipo (ya sea `int, String, double...`. Lo que no entiendo bien es lo que ello implica, el atributo `titular`, ¿ahora tiene los 4 atributos propios de Cliente? Osea ` idCliente, nombre, direcccion, telefono`. Si explica eso el tutorial, realmente no me he percatado.